# How to get atoms from an or logic by deduction proof?

Tags: math, computer-science

For example i got ¬(p∧¬r),and by deMorgan's law, i will get (¬p∨¬¬r), how to get ¬p and ¬¬r from it by logic? (Using conjunction/disjunction introduction, elimination)

Comment: without making new assumption

Comment: What do you mean, "get ¬p"? `p` and `r` are propositions. You *start* with these.

Comment: i want to get it just like from a∧b |- a, is there anyways i can get (¬p∨¬¬r) |- ¬p

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment above as soon as I posted my answer, but my network adapter crashed before I could delete it. I'm composing a new answer.

Comment: i've got ¬r as an assumption, so i need to get ¬¬r from the or logic by rules so i can use them to get ⊥, which will help me solve the problem, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Recall that (a implies b) is equivalent to ((not a) or b). Can you match that to what you have so far? Remember that (a implies b) is equivalent to ((not b) implies (not a)). You say that you're given (not r). Can you combine that with an implication?

Comment: i cannot use imply except implication introduction and elimination, so not r here cannot imply something because its not follow the implication rules

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to a deleted answer, the OP clarified their questions as follows:

> Is there anyways i can get (¬p∨¬¬r) |- ¬p

No, not without additional information or assumptions. In other words, it's only possible by adding additional statements.

---

Let's work from an example.

- Let's say `p` is *It's cloudy*.
- Let's say `r` is *It's raining*.

The following is known:

*It's false that it's cloudy and that it's not raining.* (`¬(p∧¬r)`)

Through deMorgan's Lawm, we also know the following:

*It's not cloudy, or it's false that it's not raining.* (`¬p∨¬¬r`)

We can simplify using double-negation elimination.

*It's not cloudy, or it's raining.*  (`¬p∨r`)

It's **impossible** to conclude any of the following from the above:

- *It's cloudy.*
- *It's not cloudy.*
- *It's raining.*
- *It's not raining.*

If we knew *it's cloudy* (`p`), we could conclude (by Disjunctive Syllogism) that *it's raining* (`¬p∨r, p ⊢ r`)

If we knew *it's not raining* (`¬r`), we could conclude (by Disjunctive Syllogism) that *it's not cloudy* (`¬p∨r, ¬r ⊢ ¬p`)

But without this additional knowledge, we can't eliminate `p` or `r`.

Comment: this is a good way to go but i cannot use double negation here, its not allowed

Comment: Then ignore that line. Doesn't change anything

Comment: cannot apply ND rules to sub formulas, in Natural Deduction, there is no single rule for double negation. The only rules for negation are negation introduction and negation elimination.

Comment: Disjunctive Syllogism is not allowed too, its not part of ND rules

Comment: Adding restrictions as you are doing only makes it "more impossible".

Comment: the only ways are  Assumption Introduction, Conjunction/Disjunction/Negation introduction/elimination, Falsum and Reducto Absurdium

Comment: yep but there is one way , i have spend over 11 hours on it still confused

Comment: Well, yeah, there is *one* way. It's mentioned in my answer: adding information/assumptions.

Comment: adding assumptions not allowed, i want add it so much but can't

Comment: That is the only way.